# Where can I rent a 125cc scooter in Barcelona by the month?

Tags: transportation, spain, rental, barcelona, scooters

Whenever I travel to Barcelona, I love to rent a scooter. It's a really great way to get around town.

I'm planning to be there for the month of August and would like to find places that rent long term. I'm trying to find places that have a monthly rate (rather than hourly or daily).

Requirements:

- Unlimited or a very high limit on distance
- Two helmets
- 125cc engine

Comment: According to the [US Embassy in Madrid](http://madrid.usembassy.gov/citizen-services/faq-spain.html), you have to have an International Driving Permit to drive in Spain, so if you really can't get one you are probably out of luck.  But it should be easy to get one.

Comment: I've rented multiple times in Barcelona without an IDP. The IDP is essentially just a translation.

Comment: If you have a little spare time before you go, get the IDP anyway - you can get one from AAA cheaply and quickly.

Comment: I reworded the question to be about finding places that rent long term and removed the IDP requirement.

Comment: I think you should always negotiate the price when it comes to long-term rentals.

Answer (score 2):

[Vesping Barcelona](http://vesping.com/gps-guided-tour?gclid=Cj0KEQiA-PGiBRDRz4jH9o39yZwBEiQAWCBZNRIB_Mr9jS9Bjc1m3SHtESqnLohHljZM-TDir9pTbDQaAmkF8P8HAQ) offers:

[image: TSE34064 hire details]

or Euro 1,600 for two fortnights for a 125 cc, unless you can negotiate something better. I have not seen mention of a mileage limitation.

---

Checking back in 2017 the site seems to have changed significantly and may no longer offer larger capacity scooters, nor rentals for as long as a month.

Comment: vesping.com shows Euro 795 for 14 days, plus some fees, so looks to be almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

### Scooters in Barcelona

I have never actually done this, as I believe that my feet and the Barcelona metro service are the best option for touring Barcelona. However, renting scooters is yes very common, and there are plenty of sites out there for scooter rentals. [A quick google search revealed these.](https://www.google.com/search?q=alquilar%20scooter%20barcelona&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=iceweasel-a&channel=fflb#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&channel=fflb&q=alquiler%20scooter%20barcelona&spell=1)

I clicked on a [random one](http://www.moto-rent.com), set bogus dates (from 01/08/2015 to 01/09/2015), picked the scooter I thought is newest and got a total of **345,63 €. (TAXES INCLUDED)**. Add 30Euros for extra insurance lowering the franchise to 300Euros (15Euros per week) and you are looking at less than 400Euros for a 31 day rental.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

### Advance Booking

It could probably be worth booking in advance, as I can only assume that prices levitate during high season, and as scooter availability drops. Also, I would stick with large companies (the equivalent of Hertz/Europcar so to speak) to make sure you are getting proper service and true legal policies behind the rental. Some guy on the street with an extra set of wheels to rent might be cheaper, but you never know how things might work out if you happened to crash the scooter. In these cases it is better, I think, to have a proper rental contract, with guarantees.

### Larger Wheels, Man

On a different, technical, note I would advise you to go for a scooter with large rims (in terms of diameter) as these provide more comfort when driving in the city. Smaller rims allow for manoeuvrability at low speeds and fast cornering, whereas larger rims roll easier over obstacles and are more stable at high speeds. I assume you are no Marc Marquez so you don't really care about the speed issue. However riding over potholes, and *boy* are there potholes-covered roads in Europe, with larger wheels is *way* more comfortable than with smaller wheels. [For more info see here.](http://www.scooterfocus.com/scooter_wheel_size.html)

There are other technical considerations you should keep in mind such as: are you going to use it only in the city? What's the average distance you plan on riding every day? I'll leave those for another question.